Firebase Function Deployment for Stripe
I'm working on a project using Firebase Functions with Stripe. Following these docs: https://docs.stripe.com/identity/verification-sessions
I keep getting this error when I deploy the function:

i  functions: updating Node.js 18 (2nd Gen) function createVerificationSession(us-??>central1)...
Could not create or update Cloud Run service createverificationsession, Container >Healthcheck failed. Revision 'createverificationsession-00014-jow' is not ready and >cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port >defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might >contain more information.

I check out the logs and see a few things:
{
  "textPayload": "    StripeInvalidGrantError: [class StripeInvalidGrantError extends StripeError],",
  "insertId": "663fc892000d43eabf84f867",
  [...]
  "logName": "projects/lectio-c2268/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstdout",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2024-05-11T19:35:47.208375619Z"
}

{
  "textPayload": "Default STARTUP TCP probe failed 1 time consecutively for container \"worker\" on port 8080. The instance was not started.",
  "insertId": "663fc893000cef0fae764d6a",
  [...]
}

Here's the firebase function in question:
const { onCall } = require('firebase-functions/v2/https');
const { error } = require('firebase-functions/logger');
import admin = require('firebase-admin');const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const stripe = require('stripe')(
'sk_test_51O7T...',
);

[...]

exports.createVerificationSession = onCall(async (data: any, context: any) => {
  const verificationSession = await stripe.identity.verificationSessions.create(
    {
      type: 'document',
      metadata: {
        user_id: context.auth.uid,
      },
    },
  );
  const clientSecret = verificationSession.client_secret;
  console.log('Client secret:', clientSecret);
  return { clientSecret };
});

And here's how i call it in the front end:
const stripePromise = loadStripe(
'pk_live_51O7...',
); 

function Payment() {
  const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchClientSecret = async () => {
      console.log('Fetching client secret');
      const functions = getFunctions();
      const createVerificationSession = httpsCallable(
        functions,
        'createVerificationSession',
      );

      try {
        console.log('Calling createVerificationSession');
        await createVerificationSession().then((result) => {
          console.log('Result:', result);
        });
        // setClientSecret(response.data.clientSecret);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to fetch client secret:', error);
        // Handle errors here appropriately
      }
    };

    fetchClientSecret();
  }, []);

  if (!stripePromise || !clientSecret) {
    return <p>Loading payment details...</p>;
  }

  const options = {
    clientSecret: clientSecret,
  };

  return (
    <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={options}>
      <CheckoutForm />
    </Elements>
  );
}

export default Payment;

I am running on localhost:5173 with firebase emulators
{
  "functions": {
    "source": "../../functions",
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  }
}

I am totally stumped about how to debug this! Any guidance would be super appreciated!

If you're having problems deploying your function, and the error isn't related to your own code, you should reach out to Firebase support to get assistance.  Note that the error message "Logs for this revision might contain more information" so I would try to look into that for more details.

@DougStevenson thanks for the reply - sorry what indicates that it isn't related to my code?

The error message is talking about things you don't have control over.
